# Objective-C - Finding a URL within a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

Given a large string, what is the best way to create an array of all valid urls which are contained within the string?

Comment: Is this for display in a `UITextView` or a `UILabel` or for soemthing else?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25574255/1966109) for a similar question that uses Swift 3  and gives 2 ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No need to use `RegexKitLite` for this, since iOS 4 Apple provide `NSDataDetector` (a subclass of `NSRegularExpression`).

You can use it simply like this (`source` is your string) :

```
NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray* matches = [detector matchesInString:source options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [source length])];
```

Comment: NSDataDetector is *only* available on iOS. The title of the question is "*Objective-C* Finding A URL Within A String"

Comment: True, it depends on what platform Mick is working... But looking at his last questions, he is targeting iOS.

Comment: With hindsight, it was added to the Mac in 10.7, a couple of months after the comments above.

Comment: for me it added an extra single quote to the end

Answer (score 6):

I'd use [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/) for this:

```
#import "RegExKitLite.h"

...

NSString * urlString = @"blah blah blah http://www.google.com blah blah blah http://www.stackoverflow.com blah blah balh http://www.apple.com";
NSArray *urls = [urlString componentsMatchedByRegex:@"http://[^\\s]*"];
NSLog(@"urls: %@", urls);
```

Prints:

```
urls: (
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "http://www.apple.com"
)
```

(Of course, the regex I've used there for urls is simplified, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score -1):

This is best way to extract url link.

```
NSString *url_ = @"dkc://name.com:8080/123;param?id=123&pass=2#fragment";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_];

NSLog(@"scheme: %@", [url scheme]);

NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);

NSLog(@"port: %@", [url port]);

NSLog(@"path: %@", [url path]);

NSLog(@"path components: %@", [url pathComponents]);

NSLog(@"parameterString: %@", [url parameterString]);

NSLog(@"query: %@", [url query]);

NSLog(@"fragment: %@", [url fragment]);
```

Output:

> scheme: dkc
>
> host: name.com
>
> port: 8080
>
> path: /12345
>
> path components: (
>       "/",
>       123 ) parameterString: param
>
> query: id=1&pass=2
>
> fragment: fragment