# Retrieve image url from string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm parsing an xml file and I can NSLog the parsing, but my problem is that I need to get the image url`s from this "string":

```
<p>
 <a href="http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex43.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-81" title="ex4" src="http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex43-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></a>
 <a href="http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex32.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-80" title="ex3" src="http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex32-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></a>
 <a href="http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex23.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-79" title="ex2" src="http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex23-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></a>
 <a href="http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex12.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-71" title="ex1" src="http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex12-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></a>
 </p>
```

Sorry for the plain code :)

what im using to extract the url´s is this code but its not working:

```
   NSRange start = [item.imageGallery       rangeOfString:@"http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/"];
    NSRange end = [item.imageGallery rangeOfString:@"\" "];

    int rangeLength = (int)(end.location - start.location);

    NSString *hrefString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[item.imageGallery substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start.location, rangeLength)]];
    NSLog(@"image url = %@",hrefString);
```

Comment: you need to post an example of the xml or something if you want people to help you.    This is akin to saying "my car won't start.  how do i fix it?"

Comment: Well, you can start by posting the format of the xml file and your parsing code so we can actually help you.

Comment: Try using a regular expression to filter out the URL's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a regular expression: `"src=\"([^\"]+)\""`

Here is some example code:

```
NSString *searchedString = @""  
    @"<p>"
    @"<a href=\"http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex43.jpg\"><img class=\"alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-81\" title=\"ex4\" src=\"http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex43-150x150.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\" /></a>"
    @"<a href=\"http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex32.jpg\"><img class=\"alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-80\" title=\"ex3\" src=\"http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex32-150x150.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\" /></a>"
    @"<a href=\"http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex23.jpg\"><img class=\"alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-79\" title=\"ex2\" src=\"http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex23-150x150.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\" /></a>"
    @"<a href=\"http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex12.jpg\"><img class=\"alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-71\" title=\"ex1\" src=\"http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex12-150x150.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\" /></a>"
    @"</p>";
NSRange rangeOfString = NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length]);
//NSLog(@"searchedString: %@", searchedString);

NSString *pattern = @"src=\"([^\"]+)\"";
NSError* error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *matchs = [regex matchesInString:searchedString options:0 range:rangeOfString];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matchs) {
        NSLog(@"url: %@", [searchedString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
    }
```

NSLog Output:

```
url: http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex43-150x150.jpg
url: http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex32-150x150.jpg
url: http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex23-150x150.jpg
url: http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex12-150x150.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

here, I found it for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5999294/1047258

The code from that answer:

```
NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray* matches = [detector matchesInString:source options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [source length])];
```

Then to handle the URL(s):

```
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        NSURL *url = [match URL];
        // do whatever you want with the url
}
```

Comment: I have tested it and it wont print a clean url it prints this:          2012-02-14 14:33:28.685 Excellens[37314:17003] url = <NSLinkCheckingResult: 0x87bab60>{12, 76}{http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex43.jpg}
2012-02-14 14:33:28.686 Excellens[37314:17003] url = <NSLinkCheckingResult: 0x87b9730>{157, 84}{http://www.bubblesurprise.com/WPRESS_APP/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ex43-150x150.jpg}
2012-02-14 14:33:28.687 Excellens[37314:17003] url = <NSLinkCheckingResult: 0x87b6450>{257, 3}{tel:150}

Comment: The matches are from type NSTextCheckingResult. Use [match URL] to get an NSURL object from it.