# Extract URL of Image From String

Tags: ios, url, nsstring, range

I am trying to extract the URL for an image from a string of text.  It may be from different websites, and could be any form of image (jpg, png, gif, etc.).  What would be a good way to scan the string, find any matching picture extension, and get the graphic from it?

The string may be something like this:

```
Hello, I hope you like my picture located at http://www.website.com/picture1.png.  However, if you don't, I know you'll like this one http://www.website2.org/picture2.jpg.Please refer all comments to http://www.website5.com/
```

I want to be able to scan the string for ONLY URLs of image files, and make a new string of whatever the first image URL is.  So in this string, I could create a new string that only has http://www.website.com/picture1.png

Comment: Huh, this is a bit broad, don't you think?

Comment: @H2CO3 see edit for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got from The Link [Objective-C - Finding a URL within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998969/objective-c-finding-a-url-within-a-string)

No need to use `RegexKitLite` for this, since iOS 4 Apple provide `NSDataDetector` (a subclass of `NSRegularExpression`).

You can use it simply like this (source is your string) :

```
NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray* matches = [detector matchesInString:source options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [source length])];
```

Comment: Ok, so using this, I would get an array of all the URLs contained within the string, correct?  How do I go from there to narrow it down to just 1 containing a valid image (if one exists)?

Comment: after that put a 'for loop' for the array containing **URL** and use @dmason82 code to achieve that task.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use below code after later finish with @Anup Kumar

   for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        NSRange matchRange = [match range];
        if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
            NSURL *url = [match URL];
        } else if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber) {
            NSString *phoneNumber = [match phoneNumber];
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get the extension you can use the NSString method pathExtension, this will result in a string with just the extension, so you will know if it is jpg, gif, png, etc.

```
NSString* path = @"http://location.com/pictures/image.jpg";
NSString* extension = [path pathExtension];
```

For your graphic you can use the UIImage imageWithData method, and pass it the output from NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl method, using these methods together will allow you to create a UIImage which you can then display in a UIImageView.

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:path]];
```

Hopefully that is helpful.