# Regular expression in ios to extract href url and discard rest of anchor tag?

Tags: html, ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I want to write a url extracting function in objective C. The input text can be anything and may or may not contain html anchor tags.

Consider this:

```
NSString* input1 = @"This is cool site <a   href="https://abc.com/coolstuff"> Have fun exploring </a>";
NSString* input2 = @"This is cool site <a target="_blank" href="https://abc.com/coolstuff"> Must visit </a>";
NSString* input3 = @"This is cool site <a href="https://abc.com/coolstuff" target="_blank" > Try now </a>";
```

I want modified string as `"This is cool site https://abc.com/coolstuff`

Ignoring all text between anchor tag. And need to consider other attributes like _target in anchor tag

I can do something like

```
static NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<a\shref=\"(.*?)\">.*?</a>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];;
NSString* modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:inputString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [inputString length]) withTemplate:@"$1"];
```

Works fine with input1 but fails in other cases.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C - Finding a URL within a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998969/objective-c-finding-a-url-within-a-string)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<a[^>]+href=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>.*?</a>
```

Comment: <a[^>]+href[ ]*=[ ]*\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a> is more better.  Maybe there are space between "href" and "=".

Comment: How would one use this to make the plain text clickable like a link, so the plain text when clicked will open the href link?

Answer (score 5):

Or try this one:

```
<a.+?href="([^"]+)
```

### EXPLAINED

`<a` - match opening tag

`.+?` - match anything lazily

`href="` - match href attribute

`([^"]+)` - capture href value

### OUTPUT

```
https://abc.com/coolstuff
https://abc.com/coolstuff
https://abc.com/coolstuff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<[aA].+href[ ]*=[ ]*[\\]?"(.*)[\\]".*>(.+)<\/[aA]>
```

Here, the first group ($1) captures the url. $2 captures the link text.