# Swift: check if UISearchBar.text contains a url

Tags: swift, string, cocoa-touch, nsdatadetector

How can I check if UISearchBar.text contains a URL? I thought of doing something like this:

```
if (searchBar.text == NSTextCheckingType.Link) {

}
```

but I get the error:

```
String is not convertible to NSObject
```

Comment: I get an error that says NSTextCheckingType is not convertible as String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Swift 3, you can use `NSDataDetector`. `NSDataDetector` has an initializer called [`init(types:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatadetector/1409829-init). `init(types:)` has the following declaration:

```
init(types checkingTypes: NSTextCheckingTypes) throws
```

> Initializes and returns a data detector instance.

In order to create a data detector that finds urls, you have to pass [NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstextcheckingresult.checkingtype/1411725-link) as the parameter for `init(types:)`.

---

### #1. Using `NSDataDetector` and `NSRegularExpression`'s `enumerateMatches(in:options:range:using:)` method

As a subclass of `NSRegularExpression`, `NSDataDetector` has a method called [`enumerateMatches(in:options:range:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression/1409687-enumeratematches). `enumerateMatches(in:options:range:using:)` has the following declaration:

```
func enumerateMatches(in string: String, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [], range: NSRange, using block: (NSTextCheckingResult?, NSRegularExpression.MatchingFlags, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)
```

> Enumerates the string allowing the Block to handle each regular expression match.

The Playground code below shows how to use `NSDataDetector` and `enumerateMatches(in:options:range:using:)` method in order to detect if a `String` contains `URL`s:

```
import Foundation

let testString = " lorem http://www.yahoo.com ipsum google.fr"

do {
    let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: testString.characters.count)
    let block = { (result: NSTextCheckingResult?, flags: NSRegularExpression.MatchingFlags, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        if let result = result, result.resultType == NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link {
            print(result.url)
        }
    }
    detector.enumerateMatches(in: testString, options: [], range: range, using: block)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

/*
 prints:
 Optional(http://www.yahoo.com)
 Optional(http://google.fr)
 */
```

---

### #2. Using `NSDataDetector` and `NSRegularExpression`'s `matches(in:options:range:)` method

As a subclass of `NSRegularExpression`, `NSDataDetector` has a method called [`matches(in:options:range:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression/1412446-matches). `matches(in:options:range:)` has the following declaration:

```
func matches(in string: String, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [], range: NSRange) -> [NSTextCheckingResult]
```

> Returns an array containing all the matches of the regular expression in the string.

> This is a convenience method that calls `enumerateMatches(in:options:range:using:)` passing the appropriate string, options, and range.

The Playground code below shows how to use `NSDataDetector` and `matches(in:options:range:)` method in order to detect if a `String` contains `URL`s:

```
import Foundation

let testString = " lorem http://www.yahoo.com ipsum google.fr"

do {
    let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: testString.characters.count)
    let resultArray = detector.matches(in: testString, options: [], range: range)
    for result in resultArray {
        if result.resultType == NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link {
            print(result.url)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}

/*
 prints:
 Optional(http://www.yahoo.com)
 Optional(http://google.fr)
 */
```

Answer (score 3):

I enhanced `Imanou PETIT`'s anwser.

This allows you to extract multiple URL's from a string.

```
extension String {
    var extractURLs: [NSURL] {
        var urls : [NSURL] = []
        var error: NSError?
        let detector = NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue, error: &error)

        var text = self

        detector!.enumerateMatchesInString(text, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(text)), usingBlock: { (result: NSTextCheckingResult!, flags: NSMatchingFlags, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
            //            println("\(result)")
            //            println("\(result.URL)")
            urls.append(result.URL!)
        })

        return urls
    }
}
```

An example usage:

```
var urls = text.extractURLs
for url in urls {  
     // do stuff with your URL        
     if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
         UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
         break
     }
}
```

Comment: Although I have solved this problem a long time ago, this is very helpful, thank you.